# Best alternative to Filezilla Client

Tags: windows-xp, ftp, sftp

- I'm using Window XP.
- So I m not able to use Filezilla.

Can anyone suggest the best FTP Software replacement for Filezilla?

Free software preferred.

Thanks

Comment: Try [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Comment: Consider a web-based app like Monsta FTP (disclaimer: I'm involved with this project). The future is cloud, not locally-installed apps. www.monstaftp.com

Answer (score 5):

If you only need the simple transferring of files, you don't need to install a program. You can create a shortcut to the FTP server from Explorer.

1. Open "My Network Places".
2. In the "Network Tasks" panel, click "Add a network place". This will start up the Add Network Place Wizard.
3. Click next, then select "Choose another network location" and click next.
4. Type your domain name (e.g. "ftp://ftp.website.com") then click next.
5. The next screen asks for your username. Uncheck "Log on anonymously" to enter the username, then click next.
6. Give this network place and name, then click next then finish.

This shortcut will now appear like a folder. When you double click the icon you will be asked for your log on details. You can drag and drop files just like a normal folder.

For a full step-by-step with pictures see [this link](http://efnhosting.org/tutorials/xp_ftp.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, FileZilla can run under Windows XP. You might need to get slightly older version with less blows and whistles, but still as reliable as new one. If you are after an old version of FileZilla that is compatible with Windows XP, then [this is a place to search](http://www.oldapps.com/filezilla.php?system=Windows_XP).

If you still want an alternative, then I am not sure why would you want an open source program? Did you actually mean **free**?

You did not specify what exctly do you need a server or a client.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software) on Wikipedia lists some good FTP server software.

And [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software) lists some descent FTP client software.

I am sometimes using XLight FTP - it is pretty basic but fairly good.

Comment: Yes. I need free. I need to use for upload files from my pc to server.

Comment: You are wrong dude. 
I went down to v3.9, and it still doesn't work on the XP machine I am on right now